# Multiline environment variable in Makefile

Tags: python-3.x, makefile

I am trying to pass a multiline variable to a cli program from within Makefile, but not able to do so.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: test
test: ## Run the Tests locally
        @echo $(SOME_VAR)
        r=$(echo $(SOME_VAR) | sed 's/"/\\"/g')
        python3 test_env_var.py "$(r)"
```

Where `SOME_VAR` is an env var containing multiline text string (in the end, I want this var to contain multiline JSON). Could you please suggest how can I achieve this from within Makefile?

**Python code:**

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Do you genuinely mean an environment variable, or do you actually mean a `make` variable?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I mean an environment variable as CICD pipelines these days can have variables set for deployment profiles. So, I would like to pass a config JSON to the build script. And env var is a way to pass that in CICD. We are using Makefile to run commands like test, build and deploy.

Comment: Well then, you're going to a lot of trouble to make something hard that could be easy.  See option 0 in my answer.  Or even consider having your test program read the data directly from its environment, cutting `make` out of the loop entirely.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, can't do that, as the program is `aws-cli`. Need to pass my JSON as a command argument only, as with any pre-written CLI. Thank you so much for such an elaborate answer, it really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `SOME_VAR` were indeed an environment variable -- that is, provided to `make` externally in its environment -- then you could just rely on your recipe to inherit it in its own environment:

#### Option 0

```
test:
        @echo "$${SOME_VAR}"
        python3 test_env_var.py "$${SOME_VAR}"
```

Note the doubling of the `$` character to escape it from interpretation by `make`, so that the shell performs the interpolation.

---

But I suspect that you actually mean that you have the data in a `make` variable.  In that case, your `echo $(SOME_VAR)` is problematic for pretty much the same reasons that `python3 test_env_var.py $(SOME_VAR)` would have been: not only newlines (if you really have them) but other characters that are significant to the shell, too, will be misinterpreted.  What's more, `make` implementations typically execute each line of a recipe in a separate shell, so you cannot expect to set a shell variable in one line of a recipe and read its value back in a separate line.

#### Option 1

If you were prepared to assume that the variable's value did not contain any single quotes, then you could simply quote with that:

```
test:
        @echo '$(SOME_VAR)'
        python3 test_env_var.py '$(SOME_VAR)'
```

JSON data should use only double quotes internally, so you should be ok in that sense, but if there are any single quotes within the data themselves then that's going to break.

Do note, however, that single quotes and double quotes are not wholly analogous with each other to the shell.  For example, variable expansions, command substitutions, and backslash escapes are recognized within double quotes, whereas no special characters are recognized within single quotes.  As a result, you really ought to be looking to use single quotes, quite independently from those characters' differing significance in JSON.

#### Option 2

If you are willing to rely on GNU `make`, then you can use its `subst` function:

```
test:
        @echo '$(subst ','\'',$(SOME_VAR))'
        python3 test_env_var.py '$(subst ','\'',$(SOME_VAR))'
```

That converts each single-quote within the data to the four-character sequence `'\''`.  With the overall content enclosed in single quotes, each appearance of those characters closes one single-quoted string, presents a backslash-escaped single quote (which can't appear inside a single-quoted string) and starts a new single-quoted string.

#### Option 3

But also consider just not.  Especially if you really want multi-line data, consider instead putting it in a file and having the recipe read it from there.  If necessary, it can be a built file.

```
test:
        @echo "$$(cat test-arg)"
        python3 test_env_var.py "$$(cat test-arg)"
```

Note again the doubling of the `$` character.